# How to start with JUNG programming?

Tags: jung2

I have to start with programming with Graphs and I looked on to the internet to use JUNG 2.

I have been going through the documentation, but can anyone please guide me from the beginning as to implement such programs. I have downloaded the jar files mentioned on this link: http://jung.sourceforge.net/download.html

Please can someone tell me what I should do further?

This might look like a naive question, but I've just started and would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will have to post what you have tried so far.  Otherwise I doubt you will receive any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repository (now hosted at GitHub) and the distribution files that you downloaded include a number of sample programs that use JUNG: https://github.com/jrtom/jung/tree/master/jung-samples/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/jung/samples

There's also a tutorial here: http://www.grotto-networking.com/JUNG/JUNG2-Tutorial.pdf